# Standard Random Variable Notation

Tags: self-study, random-variable

Perhaps this question is a bit basic for this area, so if this should go somewhere else, please let me know.

I am having a bit of trouble understanding random variable notation.  This is kind of spilling over into other areas of the course I am taking which is causing confusion throughout.

Can we start with something like $F_X(x)=P\left \{ X \leq x \right \}$ and break that down?

Why does the CDF side [ $F_X(x)$ ] not include any kind of random variable in the parentheses?  Is the small x on the left the same as the small x on the right?

Why does the probability of a random variable always need to be less than or equal to some variable x?  How does x relate to the CDF?

Any kind of help/videos/explanations for this would be good.  I have watched some Khan academy videos, but nothing seems to be sticking.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Where does that $X/Y$ come from? Also, as a heads up, the subscript variable is typically capitalized in order to denote that the function applies to a per iciest random variable, such as $F_X(x)$ being the CDF of some random variable $X$.

Comment: Dave, thanks!  I will edit the above question to make sure the F_X (capital) is reflected properly.  The X/Y is just an example of something I see.  I understand that X and Y are both random variables.  I suppose that is confusing.

Comment: It would have to mean that $Z=X/Y$, which is fine, but it is confusing when you don’t define $Z$.

Comment: Dave, again, thanks for the feedback!  I will just remove that line from the question as it provides no context.  And in this case, yes it is Z = X/Y.  I am into the section of the course on functions of random variables.  My lack of fundamental understanding on random variables is proving to be a big hurdle when it comes to the section I am in now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of random variable is **defined** to be a function $F_X(x)=Pr(X \le x)$. It is a convention to use $\le$, though it is not a universal one.

We  use a subscript to denote which random variable are we referring to. The $x$ on the left, and the $x$ on the right are the same $x$.

For example, if $X$ is the distribution of the height of students, then $F_X(180)=Pr(X \le 180)$ is the probability that a student height is less than or equal to $180$.